# JTextField in a loop of slider listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, listener

I'm beginner in java programing and I encounter a problem. My aim is to relate slider, which give me number of figure's vertices, with simultaneously creating JFieldText fields of coordinates as it is on picture:[image]

My attempts led me to the problem where I'm creating those fields but there are to many cols despite of taking 2 in GridLayout and when I'm decreasing the value of vertices, fields doesn't. Here is my sample of code:

```
    int vertices = 3;
    slider.addChangeListener(new SpinerListener());

    class SpinerListener implements ChangeListener {
       public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            vertices = slider.getValue();
            right.setLayout(new GridLayout(vertices, 2));//right is my panel        
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices*2; i++) {
                fields[i] = new JTextField("Field " + i);
                right.add(fields[i]);
            }
            right.removeAll();
       }

    }
```

Comment: Use a JTable and change the row count

Comment: Is it possible to change values in JTables, in running program like it's with JTextFields? It's also need in my project.

Comment: Yes of course it's possible. One way is to call the model's `getRowCount(...)` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You could...

Use some kind of `List` - which provides a concept of dynamically sizeable container of objects, instead of using an array.  With this, you could then determine if you need to add or remove items from the `List` depending on the new value of the `JSlider`.

```
private List<JTextField[]> fields = new ArrayList<>(3);

//....

class SpinerListener implements ChangeListener {

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        vertices = slider.getValue();

        if (vertices < fields.size()) {
            List<JTextField[]> oldFields = fields.subList(vertices + 1, fields.size());
            for (JTextField[] pairs : oldFields) {
                for (JTextField field : pairs) {
                    right.remove(field);
                }
            }
            fields.removeAll(oldFields);
            right.revalidate();
            right.repaint();
        } else if (vertices > fields.size()) {
            int count = (vertices - fields.size());
            System.out.println("Add " + count + " new fields");
            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                JTextField[] pairs = new JTextField[2];
                pairs[0] = new JTextField(4);
                pairs[1] = new JTextField(4);

                for (JTextField field : pairs) {
                    right.add(field);
                }

                fields.add(pairs);
            }
            right.revalidate();
            right.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

So, it's pretty basic, it simply compares the number of field pairs to the desired amount and grows or shrinks the `List` accordingly.

As to the `GridLayout`, you actually only need to set it once...

```
right = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
```

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout-int-int-)

> **Parameters:**
>  rows - the rows, with the value zero meaning
>   any number of rows.
>  cols - the columns, with the value zero
>   meaning any number of columns.

But, personally, I'd be tempted to use a `GridBagLayout`, but that's me

And because I had to test the logic...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JSlider slider;
        private int vertices = 3;
        private List<JTextField[]> fields = new ArrayList<>(3);

        private JPanel right;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            right = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
            add(new JScrollPane(right));

            slider = new JSlider();
            slider.addChangeListener(new SpinerListener());
            slider.setValue(vertices);

            add(slider, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        class SpinerListener implements ChangeListener {

            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                vertices = slider.getValue();

                if (vertices < fields.size()) {
                    List<JTextField[]> oldFields = fields.subList(vertices + 1, fields.size());
                    for (JTextField[] pairs : oldFields) {
                        for (JTextField field : pairs) {
                            right.remove(field);
                        }
                    }
                    fields.removeAll(oldFields);
                    right.revalidate();
                    right.repaint();
                } else if (vertices > fields.size()) {
                    int count = (vertices - fields.size());
                    System.out.println("Add " + count + " new fields");
                    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                        JTextField[] pairs = new JTextField[2];
                        pairs[0] = new JTextField(4);
                        pairs[1] = new JTextField(4);

                        for (JTextField field : pairs) {
                            right.add(field);
                        }

                        fields.add(pairs);
                    }
                    right.revalidate();
                    right.repaint();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

## Or you could...

Use a `JTable`, which may be simpler and easier to manage - See [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you must use JTextFields, then remove all the JTextFields *first* in the listener before re-adding the new JTextFields. You can use `GridLayout(0, 2)` for all since this means 2 columns and variable rows.

Possibly better: use a JTable and simply change the number of rows.

Comment: Ok so gridLayout helped me a lot but I have still problem with removing JTextFields, I don't have idea how to do it or maybe I don't get what you were trying to tell me. Could you expand this?